# Problen in multiple auth Attemp() in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'am bit confused by the code.

`auth::attempt()` is not working for me, can anyone help me with this?

controller.php

```
public function postLogin(Request $request) 
{
    ....
    if (\Auth::attempt('frontendUsers', $userdata)) {   
        return Redirect::back()->with('success',true);
    } else {
        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```

view.blade.php

```
<form name="myForm1" id="loginform" role="form" method="post" action="{{ action('Auth\loginController@postLogin') }}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Card No" name="cardno"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-3 clear-both height">
        <label class="remember">Remember Me:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="remember-check"/>
    </div>
    <div class="login-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
    </div>
</form>
```

model.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;


class loginModel extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table    = 'frontend_users';

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

route.php

```
Route::get('logout','Auth\loginController@getLogout');
Route::controller('/','Auth\loginController');
Route::controller('/login', 'Auth\loginController');
```

My problem is when I run my code I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in AuthenticatesUsers.php line 42: Undefined property frontend_users not found in auth.php
```

my config/auth.php

```
return [
        'multi' => [
            'users' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model'  => App\User::class,
                'table'  => 'users'
            ],
            'frontendUsers' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model'  => App\loginModel::class,
                'table'  => 'frontend_users'
            ]
         ],
         'password' => [
                'email' => 'emails.password',
                'table' => 'password_resets',
                'expire' => 60,
            ],
        ];
```

the same code works in another project

Comment: How does your `config/auth.php` look like? The part where you define your model? And is your mode.php really the file name of the class `loginModel`? You model filename should be `loginModel` or better `LoginModel` and the class should be `LoginModel` aswel not `loginModel`

Answer (score 0):

I have seen Laravel 5 doesn't any method like you wrote. \Auth::attempt('frontendUsers', $userdata). Please read again about multi-auth in document laravel site.

Auth::guard('frontendUsers')->attempt($userdata).

Comment: \Auth::attempt('frontendUsers', $userdata) ,,,, this worked when i applied in another project.....

Answer (score 0):

From the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users

> The attempt method accepts an array of key / value pairs as its first >argument. The values in the array will be used to find the user in your >database table.

You just need to pass the property which serves as username and another one which is the password as parameters to the attempt method